# Зачем для осваивания back-end нужно начинать изучение с front-end?

Tags: веб-программирование

Буду изучать back-end. Твердо уверен что хочу изучать именно это направление в Вебе. Только вот во всех курсах, статьях и т.п. советуют всем Back_end-ерам начинать изучение с html, css и даже js! 0_о... 
Я прекрасно понимаю что мне все это понадобится. И вот когда понадобится я займусь изучением оного. Ну а пока я буду вникать в основы python/php (еще не решил что выбрать).
Собственно я почему спрашиваю. КОнечно не хочется уже с самого начала пойти по неправильному пути, который еще прибавит сложностей в будущем, но также хочется изучать прямо сейчас то, что хочется :) 
Прошу помощь зала...

Comment: html и css сейчас должна знать каждая домохозяйка. Изучается это за неделю. А node.js это не js или это не бекенд?

Comment: ну вот и буду изучать html и css  когда попробую написать первый блог или простенький сайт. Сейчас то они мне на кой?
Не, не я про JavaScript писал

Comment: Без базовых познаний html и css в вебе просто делать нечего. Даже в процессе обучения php понадобится писать простой html код. JS - это не только front-end - его изучать придется с азов в любом случае. Последовательность.

Comment: Не слушайте их, я php учу на денвере тестирую, но вот только я апи пишу. Для клиента

Comment: я знаю базовые основы html, css, php, js. но они никак мне не помогуют выставлять сервисы для форнта. абстрагируйся от форнта. работай как с сервисом.

Comment: @CyberGudvin Что то я не понял, вы собираетесь изучать back-end         или какое то направление в вебе ? В чистом back вы даже задумываться о том, что к вам обращается что то, потом взаимодействующее с вебом не будете. Но с другой стороны иметь какие то знания в самом вебе надо, что бы представлять в каком виде лучше отдавать данные, что бы у фронта не было проблем с их разбором. И кстати, как не зная основ веба вы уже решили, что хотите заниматься именно бакендом и именно для веба ? На том же питоне огромная масса приложений никак с вебом не связанная

Comment: И никогда же не знаешь куда что обернется. Когда очень давно я админил большую машину с со своими языками и СУБД и вдруг начальство отправило меня послушать курс по какому то sql, которого на нашей технике и в помине не было ... Ну послушал, почему не послушать, на самом деле же все интересно ... А уже лет через 5 мне вдруг пришлось с ним работать ... И в итоге 80% моих ответов на этом ресурсе именно по SQL ;) Осваивайте все одновременно, чем больше кругозор, тем лучше